# What is needed to use Subversion as a source control

Tags: svn

I need to install subversion as a source control tool for my SSIS projects for just one user on one PC(Windows 2008 R2). Sorry to add a new post as there are many threads on this topic. But i have been trying for the last 4 hrs to find out what do i need. I understood that there are both server and client. But is it a must to have both or i can use just the client TortoiseSVN. What are the steps to install subversion. I installed and worked on Microsoft VSS before. Do i need both ApacheSubversion and TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Probably not 100% up-to-date but should get you going: [Setting up Subversion on Windows](http://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/).

Comment: @Filburt looks decent, as long as you realize the `\` are missing from paths :)

Comment: Thank you for the replies, i'm checking them at the moment.

Comment: As the author of the *Agent SVN* plug-in I know that would work with this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure local work with SVN in Windows you can have just TortoiseSVN (while I'll recommend install Subversion CLI-tools, included now as part of TSVN installation)

Using TortoiseSVN you can create (any amount) of local Subversion repositories, accessed via `file:///` protocol and use these repositories as usual "big" repositories on dedicated servers with one small difference - these repositories will not be reachable from another hosts without additional tricks (easy, because easiest server - svnserve - it also part of CLI-tools)

Comment: Along with the above helpful replies a blog i found http://rajibmahmud.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/work-with-visual-svn-server-tortoise-svn/ helped solve this and SVN is up and running on my PC:)